# Database design for an mailbox app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I am writing a small app, with Rails + MySQL, to let people send emails to each other.
For organizing the emails, I introduced labels.

I have tables that look like:

**user**

- name

**messages**

- sender_id (fk to users)
- subject
- body

**messages_users**

- recipient_id (fk to users)
- message_id (fk to messages)

**labels**

- user_id (fk to users, nullable)
- name

To let people apply labels to their messages, I can introduce one of those two joint table:

**labels_messages_users**:

- messages_users_id (fk to messages_users)
- label_id (fk to labels)

**labels_messages**

- message_id (fk to messages)
- label_id (fk to labels)
- user_id (fk to users)

Note that labels are not necessarily created by user either. So the user_id column in the table labels_messages is necessary.

I'm not a fan of this design. It's too complex and there are too many joint tables. There must be a more elegant design.

I thought about those solutions:

#### Solution #1

**messages**

- recipient_id (fk to users)
- me
- subject
- body
- sender_id (fk to users)

**labels_messages**

- label_id (fk to labels)
- message_id (fk to messages)

**labels**
- user_id (fk to users)
- name

Pros: I like this solution as it looks more like a mailbox system. Much simpler. Plus, more efficient for querying messages by label.

Cons: I will duplicate subject and body between recipients and sender. (I wonder how GMail handles this case by the way...)

#### Solution #2

**messages**

- recipient_id (fk to users)
- me
- sender_id (fk to users)
- message_content_id (fk to message_contents)

**message_contents**

- subject
- body

**labels_messages**

- label_id (fk to labels)
- message_id (fk to messages)

**labels**

- user_id (fk to users, nullable)
- name

Pros: No more content duplication. Yay!

Cons: Design seems wrong. How to decide where to set the fk between messages and message_content? They're both rely on each other.

#### Solution #3

**messages**

- sender_id (fk to users)
- subject
- body

**mail_items**

- recipient_id (fk to users)
- message_id (fk to message)

**labels_mail_items**

- mail_item_id (fk to mail_items)
- label_id (fk to labels)

**labels**

- user_id (fk to users, nullable)
- name

Pros: mail_items is not a joint table anymore (so I can introduce a new model in my app)

Cons: still searching actually...

Can you help me come up with a better solution? How does big guys in IT (like yahoo mail, gmail and all) handle this?

Thanks!

EDIT: added labels tables and clarification on how to map messages to labels.

Comment: There's no data duplication at the db level in your solution 1. It's only stored once with fk's to both. Though you are missing the fk to user in the labels for which user created the label. Though the question is if there can be multiple recipients in which case you need the second table for recipients.

Comment: > It's only stored once with fk's to both.
What do you mean? There will be N+1 more lines in this table (N is the number of recipients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this article: http://web.archive.org/web/20100823114059/http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html

I created a model receipts which belongs to a `message` and a `user`.
I then delegated `body` and `subject` to `message`.
I then created a labels_receipts table to make the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between `label` and `receipt`.

Answer (score 0):

To me the clearest way would be the following:

user

- name

messages

- sender_id (fk to users)
- subject
- body

message_recipients (required for there to be multiple recipients per message)

- recipient_id (fk to users)
- message_id (fk to message)

labels

- name
- message_id (fk to message)

Though if you have a list of labels to choose from or you wish to be able to display all the different labels, it may be easier to label table with just the name and use a join table to connect a message with labels.

Comment: There is a **labels** table that will store all the labels user created. I will then need a joint table between labels and messages (labels_messages).
I already talk about this design and I don't like it as I don't want to introduce to many join table (performance issues).